# Maven: how to check if artifact already installen to local repository

Tags: maven, build-tools

I'm writing a shell script, which should install an artifact if it isn't already installed.

Is it exist something like `mvn install:check artifact-name`?

---

I'm using: Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: RUnning the build will automatically download the missing artifacts into the local repo? Why writing a script for this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177292/how-to-determine-if-a-maven-artifact-is-in-my-repo-from-command-line

Answer (score 6):

You can try with `dependenct:get` in **offline mode** and specify your repository, the command has the following structure:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact={groupId}:{artifactId}:{version} -o -DrepoUrl=file://your/repo/path
```

**For example:**

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=junit:junit:4.10 -o -DrepoUrl=file://~/.m2/repository
```

If it finds the dependency, then you will get:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```