# Maven - Check a local dependency on Windows

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm must verify a maven local dependency into a python script. I succeed to do it on linux using this command (from  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177292/how-to-determine-if-a-maven-artifact-is-in-my-repo-from-command-line#10177411)).

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=g:a:v -o -DrepoUrl=file://~/.m2/repository
```

My problem is that I'm working with a team using Windows, Linux and Mac, under Windows I'm unable to execute this command, the repo path is the one from mvn configuration maybe the problem is coming from the way I'm calling it as parameter.

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=g:a:v -o -DrepoUrl=file://C:\Users\user\.m2\repository
```

Is someone already use this command on Windows and have any hints to solve this problem ? 
Thank you .

Comment: What error do you get when you call the command on the Windows command line?

Comment: I got a "Building failure" and maven error output is about the plugin "dependency" -> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'dependency' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\user\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reached a solution.

I'm not sure to understand but on windows firstly I must run :

`mvn dependency:get`

before running :

`mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=g:a:v -o`

I think the problem about 'dependency plugin' is solved by the first command.